# Magento Customer Store Credit REST

Tags: magento, magento2

I'm having issue applying customer store credit to an order via API

```
/rest/V1/carts/mine/balance/apply
```

This is the endpoint from M2 Swagger, but I keep getting this as response

```
{ "message": "Request does not match any route." }
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Have you got any solution ? I have faced same issue while apply store credit.

Comment: Not through REST, I had to write a custom place order which then pass $cart->setCustomerCreditAmount($credit_amount);

Answer (score 0):

**Customer balance(store credit) operations**

```
rest/V1/carts/mine/balance/apply
```

- `method - **POST**`
- `Authentication  - Bearer <customer token>`